# strokeDashedArray doesn't work (react-native-svg)

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

```
import React from 'react';
import { Svg } from 'expo';

const { Line } = Svg;

export default class VerticalDashedLine extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Svg height={this.props.height} width={1} >
        <Line strokeDashedArray='5, 5' x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2={this.props.height}/>
      </Svg>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm currently using react-native-svg.

This works perfectly fine with just **stroke**.

But **strokeDashedArray** doesn't work (on both iOS and Android). What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo. The attribute's name in SVG is: `stroke-dasharray`. You may try `strokeDasharray` instead of `strokeDashedArray`

Answer (score 4):

The SVG name is `stroke-dasharray` not `stroke-dashed-array` and In react-native there is no [kebab-case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kebab_case) thus you have to use the camelCase version of `stroke-dasharray` e.g. `strokeDasharray`.

A complete example would be:

```
                 <Line
                    strokeDasharray="5, 5"
                    x1={0}
                    x2={1}
                    y1={0}
                    y2={100}
                    strokeLinecap="round"      
                    style={{
                      stroke: 'white',
                      strokeWidth: 5,
                    }}
                  />
```